# Generics and Abstract class

Tags: c#

I have implemented Generices as following:

```
  public class GenericAnimal<T> 
  {
    public int legs;
    public void Walk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Animals Walk....");
    }
}

public class Dog 
{
    public void Bark()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Barking....");
    }
}

public class Cat 
{
    public void Mew()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mewing....");
    }
}
```

Then I am using the class as following:

```
        GenericAnimal<Dog> dogObj = new GenericAnimal<Dog>();
        GenericAnimal<Cat> catObj = new GenericAnimal<Cat>();
```

In both the dogObj and catObj, I am getting the "Walk" method. This thing I can do using  abstract class. Then what is the added advantage of using Generics over Abstract class?

Comment: in your example generic is not usable.

Comment: 7 questions and no accepted answers - If you could please mark an a question as being answered for your previous posts?

Comment: does your dogObj Bark ? does your catObj Mew ?

Comment: dont you think googling about generics would have given you a better explanation

Answer (score 5):

In your case, none. Generics make sense in scenarios where you want a code to be reusable with different types. In `GenericAnimal<T>`, you are not doing anything with `T`.

Answer (score 1):

`Generics` and `Inheritance` are two entirely different concepts and have entirely different functions. There no such comparison "what is the added advantage of using Generics over Abstract class?". If you can abstract some common functionality from all your child objects in that sense it makes sense to use `Abstract class`. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) is more information on `Generics`.

Answer (score 1):

Your specific example is better solved by normal inheritance without generics - both Dog and Cat subclass Animal. However, say you now want a list of animals. As a non-generic solution you might choose an ArrayList, to which you can add cat and dog instances. However, the Add method of ArrayList takes an object as a parameter. Therefore, you could also add a fish to the list, and a fish can't walk. When you process the list to tell all of the animals to walk, you first have to check they are an animal.

This is where generics help. You can define your list using List<Animal> and then only objects that conform to "is Animal" can be added to the list. On the assumption that a fish is not an animal, then if you try to add one you will get a compiler error. Furthermore, when you get the items in the list you get out Animal instances rather than just objects, so you can tell them to walk immediately.

Answer (score 0):

try to write that instead:

```
public class Animal
{
  public int legs;
  public void Walk()
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Animals Walk....");
  }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
   public void Bark()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Barking....");
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
   public void Mew()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Mewing....");
   }
}
```

and try making two lists: the first one is list of cats only, the second one is a list of dogs only - first without using `List<T>` and then try using `List<T>`. i think that it will help you understand it better

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to next

```
public class GenericAnimal<T> 
{
  public T Instance{get;set;}
  public int legs;
  public void Walk()
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Animals Walk....");
  }
}
```

And you will be able to use `Dog` and `Cat`. But eyossi described better code for such kind of situation.